# POP3 to POP3S proxy/gateway?

Tags: ssl, pop3

We have a very old (windows) software that is only capable of POP3 (without SSL).
We cannot change it and we do still need to have it pulling down emails from several POP3 servers for some time. However, those servers slowly turn to SSL only connections.

Is there a piece of software which acts as POP3-to-POP3S gateway or proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/downloads.html) or stud are obvious candidates (although I don't think stud is available on ms-windows).

However, requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.